# Javascript date and time comparisson

Tags: javascript

How can I compare these two date and time values:

date 1 = 2012-03-07 11:55:18

date 2 = 2012-01-02 11:02:44

and find the time difference between them?

Comment: Where do you get those values from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get seconds difference with below code,you can convert that accordingly

```
var date1=new Date("2012-03-07 11:55:18");
var date2=new Date("2012-01-02 11:02:44");
var mSeconds=date1.getTime()-date2.getTime();
alert(mSeconds/1000);​
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/XD6AQ/)

Answer (score 0):

you can convert the date objects to timestamps like
date1.getTime()
and then use those timestamps to get difference in milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

You can create the two dates with the Javascript Date object
and then compare them with the usual operators.

See [W3 Schools Example](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp)