# how to convert date difference to number in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have designed a form which contains 3 fields
From_date
To_date
No_of days
i want to calculate the difference between from_date and to_date and the difference value will be shown in nu_of days. itried this code:

```
<script>
function difference()
{
var d1=document.getElementById("P1_FROM_DATE");
var d2=document.getElementById("P1_TO_DATE");
var d3=document.getElementB`yId("P1_NO_DAYS");
if(d2.value < d1.value)
{
alert("todate should not be less than from date");
d2.focus();
return false;
}
else
{
d3.value=(d2.value - d1.value)+1;
return true;
}
}
</script>
```

when this code executes and the condition satisfies then 
the no_of_days shows me NaN. So what is the solution please tell me.

Regards
Sabyasachi

Comment: Ever taken a look at the Date class?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601461/javascript-date-and-time-comparisson/9601628#9601628

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use date-based methods on fields that only know about text. You'll need to use the Date class to convert these values from text and use those methods to perform your date arithmetic.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

A generic formula. The date[x]-format has to be ISO (e.g 'yyyy/mm/dd').

```
var diffDays = 
     Math.floor( (new Date([date1]) - new Date[date2]) / (1000*60*60*24) );
```

BTW, I suppose `document.getElementById("P1_FROM_DATE")` is an input field. In that case use `document.getElementById("P1_FROM_DATE").value` to avoid disappointments.